# problem with default font

Tags: init-file, fonts

I changed the default font of GNU emacs 24 to [DejaVu](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page) and when I want to open a file I had this weird output(characters start appearing in small size)! 
Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

I'm using emacs for several days now, so can you please explain as much as possible. Thanks!

[image: Photo]

Comment: Do you see this when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file). If so, report it as a bug, providing a step-by-step recipe to reproduce it: `M-x report-emacs-bug`. If not, recursively bisect the code you load (e.g. init file) to locate the culprit. Then report back here with a minimal recipe that uses or points to that guilty code.

Comment: Do you have that font installed on your system?

Comment: @Drew when i start Emacs using `emacs -Q` it works fine. So the problem was with the font! isn't it?

Comment: Recursively bisect your init file (comment out 1/2, then 3/4,...) to find the problem. You can use command `comment-region` to comment out selected text (or uncomment it, with prefix arg `C-u`).